# Dual-Boot Windows 10 for ARM and Raspbian

Tags: pi-3, windows-iot

I have a 1 TB HDD running Raspbian on a Pi 3. I want to try Windows 10 for ARM (NOT THE PATHETIC WINDOWS 10 IoT THING!!!) on the same system, without reinstalling Raspbian, as I have tons of programs and files on it. I have dual booted my PC with Windows and Linux successfully before by partitioning the drive.

I figure that I can boot into Raspbian, partition and format a space on my drive, then plug it into a Windows 10 PC and complete the install on that partition, then replug the HDD into the Pi and finish it like I would if I was doing it on a SD card.

Can I do this with Windows 10 ARM and Raspbian, or will I have conflicts because of the UEFI firmware being on a partitioned drive?

Answer (score 1):

After doing a few months of research, I have learned that it is possible to boot the Windows 10 ARM build from a USB device. The instructions can be found in a video series on the Novaspirit Tech YouTube channel.

I also learned when attempting to set up dualboot with Raspbian, that the UEFI firmware can't boot any version of Rasbian, as Raspbian is a 32-Bit OS, and the UEFI only boots a 64-Bit OS.

I am going to attempt to boot Pi64 from USB and see if I can install GRUB/GRUB2 in the EFI partition, so that I can set up dualboot with Pi64 and WoA on the same disk.I'll keep whoever is interested posted.

EDIT (8/28/19)

After playing around with OpenSUSE and Fedora aarch64/ARM64 builds and attempting to create a partition on the WoA install and add one of the distros on to the same drive, I couldn't get them to work properly together. Corrupt partitions, broken installs, etc. On seperate drives, I could boot either via the UEFI/EFI firmware, but not on the same drive.

I'll try to istall GRUB into the UEFI/EFI partition of the WoA install and try to install OpenSUSE and boot it properly, when I get a new pi system that I dont use everyday.

Comment: And what is the solution to your problem?

Comment: @Ingo a bit of a follow-up for you.